# FormView.DataItem is null on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am using a LinqDataSource and a FormView with paging enabled on an ASP.NET page. I am trying to access the FormView's `DataItem` property on `PageLoad` and I have no trouble on the first page load, but as soon as I use the Next/Prev page button (causing a postback) on the FormView the `DataItem` property is null, even if there a record showing in the FormView. Any ideas why it works fine on the first page load but not on a postback?

If you're curious what my `PageLoad` event looks like, here it is:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label lbl = (Label)fvData.FindControl("AREALabel");
    if (fvData.DataItem != null && lbl != null)
    {
        INSTRUMENT_LOOP_DESCRIPTION record = (INSTRUMENT_LOOP_DESCRIPTION)fvData.DataItem;
        var area = db.AREAs.SingleOrDefault(q => q.AREA1 == record.AREA);
        if (area != null)
            lbl.Text = area.AREA_NAME;
    }
}
```

Comment: probably you have to rebind your formview in page_index changing event

Comment: How can you rebind it if it's using data from a LinqDataSource control I dropped on the page? I've called DataBind() on both the FormView and LinqDataSource, but neither seem to work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The object you bind to any data-bound control **won't be persisted in the page's ViewState**

Therefore, on subsequent posts the `DataItem` property will be null unless you re-bind the control

This property will contain a reference to the object when the control is bound.

Usually you would need to access this property if you want to *do something when the objects is bound*,  so you need to react to the `DataBound` event

Example:

### Output

[image]

### Code behind

```
protected void ds_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var d = this.fv.DataItem as employee;
    this.lbl.Text = d.lname;
}
```

### ASPX

```
    <asp:LinqDataSource ID="lds" runat="server"
        ContextTypeName="DataClassesDataContext"
        TableName="employees" 
    >

    </asp:LinqDataSource>
    <asp:FormView runat="server" ID="fv" DataSourceID="lds" AllowPaging="true" 
        OnDataBound="ds_DataBound">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox Text='<%# Bind("fname") %>' runat="server" ID="txt" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:FormView>
    <br />
    <asp:Label ID="lbl" runat="server" />
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Using the `DataBound` event instead of the `PageLoad` event did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your data will not be preserved on `PostBack`. You'll need to rebind the `FormView` in the `PageIndexChanging` event using something like:

```
protected void FormView_PageIndexChanging(object sender, FormViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    FormView.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    //rebind your data here
}
```

Comment: I'm just using the LinqDataSource control dropped on the page, how can I force it to rebind the data? The paging seems to work fine and I've called `DataBind()` on both the FormView and LinqDataSource, but neither seem to work.

Comment: You'd want to DataBind your FormView. Maybe try 'EnableViewstate="true"' in your FormView?

Comment: `EnableViewState` is defaulted to true. Very weird behavior because when I page I can clearly see the data in the form view - I just can't access the DataItem :(